# How to use += operation in custom class which behaves like dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, overloading

I am trying to implement behaviour like `class['key'] += value`. So far I end up with:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = {'a': 0, 'b': 3}

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.x[key] += item

x = Example()
x['b'] = 10
print(x.x) #{'a': 0, 'b': 13}
```

I don't need `=` operation in my class, so solution above works. Anyway I would like to change it to `+=` for better readability that everybody could see what's exactly is going on there. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x['b'] = 10` is implemented by `x.__setitem__('b', 10)`.

`x['b'] += 10` is implemented by `x.__getitem__('b').__iadd__(10)`.

You can't define a method on `Example` itself to handle `+=` here. There is no "augmented item setter" like `__isetitem__`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified example code according to @chepner answer. Thank you, this solves my problem:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = {'a': 0, 'b': 3}

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.x[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.x[key]

    def __iadd__(self, key, other):
         return self.__getitem__(key) + other

x = Example()
x['b'] = 21
x['b'] += 10

print(x.x) #{'a': 0, 'b': 31}
```